# Compare Current Row with Previous/Next row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, row

I have a table named team and it like below: I just added a row_number in the 3rd column

```
RaidNo  OutComeID   RN
2           15      1
4           15      2
6           14      3
8           16      4
10          16      5
12          14      6
14          16      7
16          15      8
18          15      9
20          16      10
22          12      11
24          16      12
26          16      13
28          16      14
30          15      15
32          14      16
34          13      17
```

When the `OutcomeId` came as 16 then start with one and 16 comes consecutively, add one by one. And the results be like

```
RaidNo  OutComeID   RN  Result
2           15      1   0
4           15      2   0
6           14      3   0
8           16      4   1
10          16      5   2
12          14      6   0
14          16      7   1
16          15      8   0
18          15      9   0
20          16      10  1
22          12      11  0
24          16      12  1
26          16      13  2
28          16      14  3
30          15      15  0
32          14      16  0
34          13      17  0
```

Help me to get the result.

Comment: should we go for select statement or do this in table column?

Comment: Whatever it may be, No problem about that.

Comment: I think the LAG function is what you are looking for here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT RaidNo, OutComeID, RN,
       CASE 
          WHEN OutComeID <> 16 THEN 0
          ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OutComeID, grp ORDER BY RN) 
       END AS Result
FROM (
   SELECT RaidNo, OutComeID, RN,
          RN - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OutComeID ORDER BY RN) AS grp
   FROM mytable) AS t
ORDER BY RN
```

Field `grp` identifies slices (also called islands) of consecutive records having the same `OutComeID` value. The outer query uses `grp` in order to enumerate each record that belongs to a `'16'` slice. The records that belong to the other slices are assigned value `0`.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/JPZR45691)